# How to skew text in Google drawings?

Tags: google-drawings

In Google Drawings how can I skew text? Make it lean over to the left or right?  I tried dragging the little blue dot but it just rotates the whole text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select multiple objects > rotate > resize.
As shown here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vT7n3-l3H86MDfWluFyQbFNaXWMciZ3M/view

Comment: Dude.  This is amazing, I never would have guessed this.